# How to copy PPT chart data to XLS most efficiently with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to copy chart data from hundreds of PPTX files, each having approx. 40 charts, into an Excel file. This code here runs, after some trial and error, stable, but takes about 2-3 minutes per file. I wonder if there is a faster way to extract the data from the PPTs?
Many thanks for any ideas...
Marco

```
Sub CopyPPTChartdataToXLS()
        
    Dim ppApp, ppFile, ppSlide, ppShape As Object
    Dim ppSlideNr, ppShapeNr As Byte
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)      'this is the worksheet to insert the data
    
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApp.Visible = True
    Set ppFile = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="c:\dummyFile.pptx")
        
    For ppSlideNr = 1 To ppFile.Slides.Count        'runs through all slides
        Set ppSlide = ppFile.Slides(ppSlideNr)
        
        For ppShapeNr = 1 To ppSlide.Shapes.Count   'runs through all shapes on slide
            Set ppShape = ppSlide.Shapes(ppShapeNr)
                
                With ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
                    wsDestination.Range("A2:J101").Value = .Sheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Value
                    .Close
                End With
            
            End If
                                         
            Call DataProcessing                     'sub will use the data for quality checks
        
        Next ppShapeNr
    Next ppSlideNr
    
    Set ppSlide = Nothing
    Set ppShape = Nothing
    Set ppFile = Nothing
    Set ppApp = Nothing
           
End Sub
```

Comment: If the structure of the data is always the same (same amount of columns) you could "collect" them in an array first - and then write the array to the sheet. This would increase performance massivly. Question: what happens in DataProcessing - could this be the routine that slows everythin down? Would it be possible to run it only once after all data are inserted. Check out the tips and tricks to enhance excel vba performance - just google for these keywords.

Comment: Btw: With the current code you will have only the data of the last slide in your wsDestination sheet as you write the values to the same range over and over again.

Comment: Hi Ike, the structure of most of the charts within a PPT are different, but the maximum no. of columns is 10, so using an array might be okay. I used a timer to determine the time requirements of the different steps of the process. In absolute terms, opening the PPT and saving the XLS require the most time. Extracting the data from a specific chart takes only approx. 2 sec., but given the number of charts in a file that sums up to more than a minute. And yes, this code copies the results at the same range, where some quality checks are done with the data and the results are logged elsewhere.

Comment: Then I don't think there is nothing to optimize. The only thing you can try is removing the `close` - but I don't know how much time that will save.

Comment: Ike, writing the chart data first in an array and than writing the array content to a range saved in total approx. 30% time. Whow, great idea, many thanks! BTW, I found that without .close, the process takes longer with each additional chart. That's a bit funny, since the code doesn't actively opens the chart data table...anyway, that's the solution now:  `arr = ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Value
 wsChartTab.Range("A2:J101") = arr`

Comment: What are you doing in DataProcessing? Would it be possible to pass the array to that sub and work there with the array values as well? By that you could avoid writing the values to a sheet which would definitly save additional time

Comment: Minor point that probably has no major effect on processing time, but your variable declarations aren't doing what you think they are.  For example, Dim ppApp, ppFile, ppSlide, ppShape As Object gives you one object variable, ppShape, but doesn't declare a type for the other variables, so VBA treats them as Variants.  You can, for instance, do ppApp = "Oh my, this isn't what I though it would be at all!" then MsgBox TypeName(ppApp) and you'll see that it's treated as a string.  Dim each on its own line to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: Ah, many thx, I wasn't aware of that. Will change that. In this context: I observed that the macro will produce an occasional run time error "workbook.open failed", which occurs more often without the `workbook.close` and also when I copy the chart data to the array as suggested by Ike. It doesn't appear always with the same charts/files, so I wonder if the main benefit of the `.close` statement is to slow down the macro. I just tried to use `DoEvents` before copying the chart data and it seems to avoid the error entirely, also it slows down the macro. Might that be related to the var dec.?